# printPreviewDialog show too many windows

Tags: windows, forms, printing, c++-cli

I would like to use printPreviewDialog control. I add 4 controls: richTextBox, button, printPreviewDialog and printDocument. For printDocument1 I add:

```
    private: System::Void printDocument1_PrintPage(System::Object^  sender, System::Drawing::Printing::PrintPageEventArgs^  e) {
               printDocument1->Print();
               e->Graphics->DrawString(richTextBox1->Text,richTextBox1->Font, Brushes::Black,(float)80,(float)80 );
    }
```

For button:

```
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    printPreviewDialog1->Document = printDocument1;
    printPreviewDialog1 -> ShowDialog();
     }
```

Code is ok, i can build and run aplication. But when i click on the button i have received something like this:

http://www.screenr.com/fJr8

Can anyone help me? Thanks guys!

Comment: I wonder if this line; `printDocument1->Print();` is recursively calling the `printDocument1_PrintPage` event

Comment: @CarlWinder - thanks for quick answer. You're right, when i delete `printDocument1->Print();` preview dialog works propertly, but ... how i can print document without using `printDocument1->Print();` ??

Comment: `ShowDialog` will return a value like `Ok` or `Cancel`, I can't remember off the top of my head what the actual code is called.  But you would check the return code from `ShowDialog` if it's `Ok` then callthe `Print` function.

Comment: @CarlWinder : thanks dude :) it's all what I want to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call PrintDocument::Print() in the PrintPage event handler.  All hell will break lose when that Print() method call invokes the PrintPage event handler again.  It takes a while to get your program to crash with this website's name, you'll probably run out of your quota for handles first.

Just remove the statement, it does not do anything useful.